# Is the Old World officially destroyed?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

It was obvious from the very beginning that the world of Warhammer Fantasy is doomed and actions of either individuals or nations can only postpone the inevitable. Then came "[The End times](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TabletopGame/WarhammerTheEndTimes)" (tvtropes warning!!!!) which proved exactly that.

Does it mean that the Old world is officially destroyed and Games Workshop/Black Library is not planning/allowing to create alternate story/more optimistic continuation?

Comment: The destruction of the old world also destroyed all interest I will ever have in what was previously known as Warhammer Fantasy. Humans all look like space marines now, everything not already covered by CW to GW is killed and given a new name, and nobody with any investment in the game has any interest in continuing. Here is a hint GW. Fantasy players want Fantasy. 40K players and those interested in Sci Fi will play 40K. Sci Fi interest will not transition into AoS interest and older players aren't going to introduce new ones now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Old World is about as dead as it's possible to be.

For a start, the Skaven blew up the moon and a good chunk of the earth along with it.

Every single elf is dead.

The Chaos gods literally walked out of the warp and killed everything after Archaon opened that warp gate below Middenheim.

GW was really trying to hammer home the fact that the Old World is dead.

But, with AOS, any (every?) hero or villian from the Old World can be reincarnated as one of Sigmars new super soldiers or as an agent of Chaos.

So while the Old World itself is no more, the characters themselves may very well reappear in new story arcs.

If you read the very first AOS book, you'll notice a good chunk of time is spent explaining that Sigmar's new soldiers can almost remember their previous lives, but not quite.

I think BL purposely kept it as ambiguous as possible in case they felt like bringing some Old World characters back.

Comment: That kinda sucks. Its one thing to kill your favorite character (hello GoT!) and complete another to blow up whole world. I personally believe it was a shot in the foot, because personally it puts me off from having any contact with Warhammer because well.. you already know how the story ends. And i.e. "Warhammer Total War" is supposed to come this year...

Comment: @Yasskier I literally couldn't agree with you more! I invested years (and no small amount of money) in Warhammer fantasy stories and novels.  And now... everyone's dead. And it makes Total War pretty damn pointless.